# List Range Refinement

Tags: python

I have been using the `a[0:2]` format for ranges but it has been bothering me that if I have `a = range(0, 5)` I get `a[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` but if I use `a[0:-1]` I get `a[0, 1, 2, 3]`.

I know if I use `a[0:]` I get the full range, but if I want to have the end of the range defined by a variable (example: `c = -1` then `a[0,c]`) there is no way for me to get the full range without using a conditional statement (for instance: `if c == -1: c = None`).

Is there some nice format that I could use to be able to access the whole range while using variables as the limits?  Or am I stuck needing a conditional statement?

Thanks.

Edit:  It appears I have two options available, I can either set the variable to `None` conditionally or I can set the variable so that the last term is set at `len(a)`.  I am not 100% sure which way I am going to go with yet, but thank you all for your responses.

Comment: Don't use `-1` as a sentinel value. Coming from C-like language the temptation is strong, but resist.

Comment: Why not?  And how else would I grab the last term? Is it only not OK to use it as a range terminator or is it not OK to use this format `a[-1]` as well?  How should it be done?

Comment: @msw Could you point me at the correct way to get to the sentinel value?  Thanks.

Comment: It looked as if you were using -1 as a "can't happen" value like EOF or  NULL in C. Python has a not-a-value called `None` which also accidentally happened to work for your slices. From a style/design perspective `if x is None:` is far more Pythonic than any other sentinel value you might pick.

Comment: And since I'm talking about style, http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ is the bible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assign `None` to `c`:

```
c = None
a[2:c]
```

It works as you want. Actually that's how slices (not ranges) are created.

They are actually ordinary Python objects. You can even use them inside `[]`.

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
s = slice(2, None)
a[s]  # equal to a[2:]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP already knows this ('there is no way for me to get the full range without usiong a conditional statement ...')

Comment: This is the direction I am sort of going, but in order to set c as None I need to use a conditional statement, and there just seems like there should be a cleaner way.  If there isn't, well there isn't.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`a[0:]` is just syntactic sugar for `a[0:len(a)]`

Thus

```
c = len(a)
a[0:c]         #a[:c], a[:], a[0:] all work as well
```

Gives you the full range.

Comment: That is interesting.  I thought I would get an out of range error, but it works.

Comment: The end parameter in slice notation is non-inclusive, so it basically returns a list of all the elements from index 0 to index (len(a)-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator:

```
a[0:c if c>0 else None]
```

But that's pretty ugly.

I think the better question is "Why do you want to use -1 to get the full slice?".  Python already uses `-1` to get up to (but not including) the final element.  Changing that behavior just leads to unexpected results for people familiar with the language.  Just document the fact that if the user of this function wants to get the full slice, they should pass `None`.

Comment: I was using the -1 format because it stays numerical and I can just multiply the number of terms I want to be from the end by -1 and get that term (works for single selection `a[-1]` but not for the range `a[0:-1]`.  I just figured there must be a built in way to do this, that is why I am asking.  But it is looking like I should just use a conditional statement and use `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice`:

```
endLimit = int(raw_input("what is the limit?"))
if endLimit == 0:
    endLimit = None
range(5)[slice(0,endLimit)]
```

slice is in fact the object the represents the `[start:end:jumps]` part of the `range(5)[start:end:jumps]`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Now that I understand exactly what OP is looking for, this'd be the way to do it:

```
a[0:c if c != 0 else len(a)]
```

Which uses a ternary, or if you really really really don't want to use a conditional, I am pretty certain this does exactly what you want and gives you a full slice on c = 0:

```
a[0:((c-1) % len(a)) + 1]
```

---------------------- Old Post ---------------------------

Well, I may be missing something, but you can go arbitrarily high.  If you do:

```
a = range(5)
a[0:200]
```

You get:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So if c is just growing or doing it's own thing the full range will be given every time c ≥ len(a).

Comment: The `range` was just an example.  The lists I have are of arbitrary length from outside data.  I need to be able to be able to slice off a known quantity of points from the end of the list.  Your method would not allow for that easily.

Comment: Ah gotcha.  So you need to be able to say [0:-7] to get all but the last 7.  Would you ever want [0:0] to return an empty list, or would that be meaningless in your situation?

Comment: I cannot see any application for `a[0:0]` in my case, but I would like to be able to easily get the full range of data including the last term (if I want).  From what I have gathered there are two methods to do this (see my edit).

Comment: Yep, gotcha.  Well, I edited mine. Two working methods, one with a ternary, one using modulo.  Both should work the way you want them to and give you a full slice on c = 0.  (You don't want a full slice on c = -1 because that has an actual non-empty list meaning.)